# Is there a wordpress plugin to make a slideshow like this one?

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress, html, slideshow

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin to produce a slideshow for use on the front page of a website.  It should work as closely as possible to the one on here:  http://www.cit.lasmit.co.uk/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin
[Easy Rotater](http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/wordpress/)

Also:
[Conslider](http://workshop.rs/2010/05/coin-slider-4-wordpress/)

Comment: Hi Shehzad, thanks for this. They both look great, I was really looking for something which is HTML5/JS and where I can have text to the right.  Will bear those ones in mind for future projects though.  Thanks again.